# Dynamic SQL :: Calculate percentage of NULLs per index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, dynamic-sql

I have a query that help me list all index in a database and works pretty well:

```
SELECT TableName = t.name, 
       IndexName = ind.name, 
       IndexId = ind.index_id, 
       ColumnId = ic.index_column_id, 
       ColumnName = col.name,
       --(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / count(*) FROM t.name) as nulls_percent,
       ind.*, 
       ic.*, 
       col.*
FROM sys.indexes ind
     INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ind.object_id = ic.object_id
                                        AND ind.index_id = ic.index_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                   AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
     INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE ind.is_primary_key = 0
      AND ind.is_unique = 0
      AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0
      AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY t.name, 
         ind.name, 
         ind.index_id, 
         ic.is_included_column, 
         ic.key_ordinal;
```

Unfortunately if I uncomment the 6th line the word `t.name` is underlined in red and if I run the query I receive the error:

```
Invalid object name 'TableName'.
```

How can I make this subquery work?

The goal is to have a percentage of `NULLs` on each column

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL.  You have to loop through the results of the first query and either generate one big query or a bunch of smaller queries in strings.

Comment: Considering that, normally, an `INDEX` covers multiple columns (apart from the `CLUSTERED INDEX`, which is normally a single column) what would you expect then? That all the columns have the value `NULL`? Are you including `INCLUDED` columns in those columns, or just the columns that are ordered on?

Comment: @Larnu, if you run the first query you will see that the statement takes only 1 table and 1 column. I will edit and be more specific.

Comment: *"if you run the first query you will see that the statement takes only 1 table and 1 column."* That first query isn't parametrised; it runs for the entire database and will return details of many indexes, on many tables, and those indexes may, or may not, have many columns.

Comment: @Larnu yeah but that is not a problem as long as we have 1 table name and 1 column name per row. And this is what I have

Comment: Yes, but an index contains **many** columns. So querying *one* column of that index doesn't tell you the percent of that index that is `NULL`. If you jsut want to count the `NULL` values in a column you could use something like this [script I wrote](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/count-non-null-rows-and-get-definition) and flip the logic to `NULL`, or add an extra column for the `NULL` as well.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I executed it, is not exactly what I wanted. I need the percentage of ´NULLs´ per column to determine what index I can put on it

Comment: Yes, so count the `NULL`, and total rows, and work it out from that, @FrancescoMantovani. Working out a percentage is basic maths: `{Sub set} / {Full Set} = Percentage`

Comment: @Larnu, do you think a cursor can help me archive this goal?

Comment: Personally I would avoid a cursor, due to their inherently slow nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and query are quite interesting and can be resolved with the help of statistics which always exist for columns participating in a index as is the case of the columns your are selecting in your query.

For accurate results, it is beneficial to update the statistics before running the query I'm providing below.

```html
;WITH cteColumnAllStats AS
(
    SELECT
        ST_COL.object_id,
        ST_COL.column_id,
        ST_COL.stats_id,

        -- NOTE: order no among stats of the same column
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(
                PARTITION BY
                    ST_COL.object_id,
                    ST_COL.column_id
                ORDER BY
                    ST_COL.stats_id
            ) AS StatsOrderNo
    FROM sys.stats ST
    INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns ST_COL
        ON  ST_COL.stats_id = ST.stats_id
        AND ST_COL.object_id = ST.object_id
)
,cteColumnFirstStats AS
(
    SELECT
        ST_COL.object_id,
        ST_COL.column_id,

        -- NOTES:
        -- =====
        -- this would be null if there were no statistics for the column
        -- however not in this case because we are only considering columns
        -- participating in an index and all indices have statistics behind
        -- the scenes.
        --
        -- Also consider whether the statistics have been updated:
        -- If they have, the result will be a whole number (without decimals)
        -- and the result is exact.
        -- If they have not, the result is an estimate and in most of the cases
        -- there will be decimals or even produce a negative result.
        --
        -- If you want accurate results, you need to update the statistics:
        -- EXEC sp_updatestats
        --
        SUM(ST_HIST.range_rows) + SUM(ST_HIST.equal_rows) AS NonNullsRowCount
    FROM cteColumnAllStats ST_COL

    -- NOTE: this is the important bit
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_histogram(
        ST_COL.object_id,
        ST_COL.stats_id
    ) ST_HIST

    WHERE   ST_COL.StatsOrderNo = 1 -- take only the first stats for the column
    GROUP BY
        ST_COL.object_id,
        ST_COL.column_id
)
    SELECT TableName = t.name, 
           IndexName = ind.name, 
           IndexId = ind.index_id, 
           ColumnId = ic.index_column_id, 
           ColumnName = col.name,

           -- NOTE: included these columns for reference purposes (PLEASE REMOVE)
           SIND.rowcnt AS [RowCount],
           ST_COL.NonNullsRowCount,
           SIND.rowcnt - ST_COL.NonNullsRowCount AS NullsRowCount,

           --(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / count(*) FROM t.name) as nulls_percent,
           CASE
                -- NOTE: stats are definitely out of date
                WHEN SIND.rowcnt < ST_COL.NonNullsRowCount THEN NULL

                -- NOTE: stats could be out of date (good to update them first)
                -- Also we don't want a divide by 0 hence the NULLIF
                ELSE (SIND.rowcnt - ST_COL.NonNullsRowCount) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SIND.rowcnt, 0)
           END as nulls_percent,

           ind.*, 
           ic.*, 
           col.*
    FROM sys.indexes ind
         INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ind.object_id = ic.object_id
                                            AND ind.index_id = ic.index_id
         INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                       AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id

    -- NOTE: this gives you the COUNT(*) without querying the table
    INNER JOIN sys.sysindexes SIND
        ON  SIND.id = t.object_id

        -- NOTE:
        -- 0 means Heap
        -- 1 means Clustered Index
        -- Only these are reliable to use their rowcnt.
        -- There's always 1 of these and not the other.
        AND SIND.indid < 2

    -- NOTE: inner join is OK here because all columns participating in a index
    -- have associated statistics
    INNER JOIN cteColumnFirstStats ST_COL
        ON  ST_COL.object_id = t.object_id
        AND ST_COL.column_id = col.column_id

    WHERE ind.is_primary_key = 0
          AND ind.is_unique = 0
          AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0
          AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    ORDER BY t.name, 
             ind.name, 
             ind.index_id, 
             ic.is_included_column, 
             ic.key_ordinal;
```

Comment: You indeed have a @LuckyBrain. Of course using the column statistics is the best way

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have a list of columns from various tables, and for each of those column you wish to determine the percentage of NULLs.

There's a similar question and answer here [SQL Query that grabs number of nulls from each column for a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343941/sql-query-that-grabs-number-of-nulls-from-each-column-for-a-db/64344437#64344437)

Regarding loops - as you'll be reading from one table, then the next, then the next... using a loop of some sort is needed as per @Gordon's comment (well, other than writing each command separately).

The basic approach is to

- Create the list of tables/columns you want to interrogate
- Create a table to hold results/output
- Dynamically create the SQL to read the number of rows and number of NULLs, and save that in your results/output table

In my answer, I suggested creating a wide table (with many pairs of columns - one for column name, one for number of NOT NULLs) e.g., col1_name, col1_num, col2_name, col2_num, etc.

The advantage of the above is for performance - you can use just one full table read to do all the number crunching and then put the values into the results table.

The OP chose a slightly different approach, where they interrogated each column one at a time. While performance is lower (e.g., needs to read each table multiple times - once per column), it

- Gave clearer output (e.g., table name, column name, number of rows, number of NULLs)
- Allowed other stats to be run e.g., getting min and max values

If you only need to run it once to get a snapshot of the database, and are fine with the temporary performance hit, then having your answer in 1-row-per-table-column is a decent solution.

Taking the 'good bits' from that previous question, I'd suggest

- Making either a temporary table (or even a normal table in a new database specifically for this) that has fields Database_name, Schema_name, Table_name, Column_name. This is input for loops.
- Fill it with the columns you want to review
- Make another table to store output, with Database_name, Schema_name, Table_name, Column_name, Num_Rows, Num_NotNULL
- Write a loop to get the next column name etc into variables
- Run a command similar to

```
-- Assume @Database_Name, @Schema_Name, @Table_Name, @Column_Name have been taken from the loop
SET @CustomSQL = '
    INSERT INTO TableResults (Database_Name, Schema_name, Table_Name, Column_Name, Num_Rows, Num_NonNull)
    SELECT  ''' + @Database_Name + ''', 
            ''' + @Schema_Name + ''', 
            ''' + @Table_Name + ''', 
            ''' + @Column_Name + ''',
            COUNT(*) AS Num_Rows, 
            COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name) + ') AS Num_NotNULL
    FROM    ' + QUOTENAME(@Database_Name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@Schema_Name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

EXEC (@CustomSQL);
```

An example SQL command created by that would be

```
INSERT INTO TableResults (Database_Name, Schema_name, Table_Name, Column_Name, Num_Rows, Num_NonNull)
    SELECT  'SalesDB', 
            'dbo',
            'ProductList', 
            'ProductName',
            COUNT(*) AS Num_Rows, 
            COUNT([ProductName]) AS Num_NotNULL
    FROM    [SalesDB].[dbo].[Products];
```

Of course, you then need to do the simple maths to get your required number e.g., to get number of NULLs, subtract the number of NotNULLs from number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

SELECT TableName = t.name, 
       IndexName = ind.name, 
       IndexId = ind.index_id, 
       ColumnId = ic.index_column_id, 
       ColumnName = col.name,
       --(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / count(*) FROM t.name) as nulls_percent,
       CAST(-1 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS nulls_percent--,
       --ind.*, 
       --ic.*, 
       --col.*
INTO #TEST
FROM sys.indexes ind
     INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ind.object_id = ic.object_id
                                        AND ind.index_id = ic.index_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                   AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
     INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE ind.is_primary_key = 0
      AND ind.is_unique = 0
      AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0
      AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY t.name, 
         ind.name, 
         ind.index_id, 
         ic.is_included_column, 
         ic.key_ordinal;


DECLARE @DynamicTSQLSTatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@TableName SYSNAME
       ,@ColumnID INT
       ,@nulls_percent DECIMAL(9,2);

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #TEST WHERE [nulls_percent] = -1)
BEGIN;

    SELECT TOP 1 @DynamicTSQLSTatement = '(SELECT @nulls_percent = SUM(CASE WHEN ' + ColumnName + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / count(*) FROM ' + TableName+' )'
                ,@TableName = [TableName]
                ,@ColumnID = [ColumnId]
    FROM #TEST 
    WHERE [nulls_percent] = -1;

    --SELECT @DynamicTSQLSTatement

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLSTatement, N'@nulls_percent DECIMAL(9,2) OUTPUT', @nulls_percent = @nulls_percent OUTPUT;


    UPDATE #TEST
    SET nulls_percent = ISNULL(@nulls_percent,0)
    WHERE [TableName] = @TableName
        AND [ColumnId] = @ColumnID;

END;

SELECT *
FROM #TEST;
```

Of course you need to improve it. For example add the `schema` name of each table, too.